# Basis and Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey can some help me with this question:

I know that $C$ is linearly independent and now I have to check if it spans $P_{2}$, but I can't visualize how I can do that. Thanks.

$C = \left\{ 1 + x + x^2,\ \ \ 2 + x + 2x^2 , \ \ \ 1 + x + 3x^2 \right\}$

Determine whether $C$ is linearly independent. Is $C$ a basis for $P_2$?

Comment: Im guessing $P_2$ means polynomials of degree at mosttwo, but you dont need to prove that it spans it, because $P_2$ is of dimension $3$ and you have three independent vectors. They must form a basis!

Comment: @user60887 Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: ok just did. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just set up a coefficient matrix with respect to the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$. That is $A = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 \\  2 & 1 &  2 \\   1 & 1 &3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1\\x\\x^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$  and row reduce to see if the columns are linearly independent which they should be. And C should form a basis.